# How can i change angular app name without making new one?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I create angular app with

```
ng new angular-excel-example
```

so when the app is generated, it makes - angular-excel-example to be used everywhere.

For example

**package.json file - name property inside**

```
 {
  "name": "angular-excel-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
...
}
```

**angular.json file**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-excel-example": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-excel-example",
...
```

is there anyway that i can change the app name dynamicaly - everywhere without breaking something - for example the configuration in angular.json file etc.

from angular-excel-example to some-new-name

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the "find and replace in every file" feature in the code editor. This way every occurrence of `angular-excel-example` is found and it can be checked before it is changed to `some-new-name`.

As an example in Visual Studio Code press `CTRL+SHIFT+F` and open the "replace" part with the arrow icon and check each change below at the listed files. (I would not go for "replace all", as it may replace some places that should not be touched.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

untill now there is no command in angular cli to replace name of project
the most effient way is to search the name in whole project and replace it